# Why I am seeing two different values for java.util.Date?

Tags: java.util.date

I have a table "Foo" to query programmatically by web application (jsf+spring dao+hibernate). The table has many columns and one of them is date column that its data type is CLOB but data is registered as MM/dd/yyyy format in string. The id column is primary key for the table.

At one point, date value was Feb 16, 2018.

```
---------------------
|  id  |   date     |
---------------------
| 1000 | 02/16/2018 |
---------------------
```

Today I set it as March 16, 2018 via web application through following code.

```
 Foo foo = tableFooRepository.findById(..); // returns a row in where date is 02/16/2018  
 SimplDateFormat sdf = new SimpelDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // <-- added originally missed statement
 Date lastDate = sdf.parse(foo.getDate());
 Date today = <using Calendar.getInstance I have today's date as Fri Mar 16 00:00:00 EDT 2018>
 if (lastDate.before(today)) {
      foo.setDate(sdf.format(today));
 } else {
   // do something else
 }
```

Very straightforward process. First time code was executed, date was properly set to "03/16/2018" for the id 1000 in the table.

The problem I having is if I run same code again else statement should be hit but it keeps hitting if statement. When I printed out value lastDate, surprisingly lastDate came out as "Thu Mar 15 20:00:00 EDT 2018".

```
Logger.info("lastDate :: " + lastDate); // Thu Mar 15 20:00:00 EDT 2018
```

However if I convert date to string via SimpleDateFormat object, the output is "03/16/2018".

```
Logger.info("lastDate :: " + sdf.format(lastDate));
```

I am not sure why lastDate has two different values.

Update:

Answer is found. Plz refer to my last comment. I added originally missing statement into the original water down version of code for the clarification of the question. Had this statement was added, the question would have been clear for others to understand what went wrong.

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

My local jvm is set to "America/New York" timezone however when I convert string MM/dd/yyyy to date object via a formatter, timezone "UTC" was used so that output was different. today was using eastern daylight saving zone but lastDate was using "UTC". Under the hood date value itself was consistent but formatter added different make up on top of it so that it looked different.

Comment: Dates are immutable so it's impossible for `lastDate` to change; unless you're reassigning it somewhere. It could be a time zone issue or something when the date is being stringified.

Comment: since you mentioned a time zone issue. I noticed one time lastDate was in est then when I set it as today it is in edt.

Comment: There. But again, Dates are immutable, so that's likely just one formatter displaying using one time zone, and another formatter another. The time zone itself can't actually change unless you create a new Date.

Comment: It was a timezone issue. What I have posted was very water down version of inherited instruction. There was a statement timezone force to set as UTC by a reference variable for simpleDateFormat object (sdf). My local jvm reads timezone as EDT but sdf forces it to use UTC so that when 02/16/2018 was retrieved and converted to date object it got translated differently. Thank you for your input Carcigenicate.